# How to add reference of Class library project having EF6 into Asp.net 5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, sqlite

I want to use EF6 with database first approach in Asp.net 5 project. As Aps.net 5 has no way to add "Ado.net entity class", I have decided to create separate class library  with EF6 which contains everything like entities and dbcontext.  And then I have added the reference of that class library to ASp.net 5 project.

I am giving connection string from Asp.net 5 project it is something looks like:

```
  var connStirng = "metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6; provider connection string='data source=\"" + dataDirectory + "NHDB.data\";journal_mode=WAL;cache=shared;synchronous=0;Version=3;'";

  var entities = new NHDBEntities(connStirng);
```

When I tried to query the database I am getting an error.

Schema specified is not valid. Errors:

```
    Model1.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
```

This error make sense. But I am not sure where to give provider as in Asp.net 5 project there is no config file.

Can someone please help me out to come out from this issue.

Thanks,
Parthiv

Comment: Although you target entity framework in the class library, it will setup the various app config xml settings in that class library.  However, when you reference the class library from your ASP NET 5 project, you will need to effectively copy that EF XML configuration from the app.config to the ASP.NET 5 project. I've installed EF in the ASP NET apps via Nuget I've done previously to do this, where the Nuget package will add that configuration for you.

Comment: @Andez : Thanks for you comment. I tried to install EF with Nuget package manager as well as using Package Manager console in Asp.net 5 project, but it still does not generate any kind of XML file or content related to EF. Could you please let me know further steps or code sample which I can refer. Looking forward to hear you soon.